# Problem with conditional rendering with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't really have an error but I'm not getting the desired outcome. I have a Flask API as my backend. It returns JSON data, this data is then passed to the React frontend to be displayed after certain actions such as a button click.

The Flask backend is working fine, the data is being sent to the React frontend and I can use `console.log(data)` to see it in the console.

The issue is I tried doing something to make it so that while the data is being fetched from the API, I want a message such as "Loading..." to be displayed.

Here's what I did in that regard.

```jsx
const [data, setData] = useState([{}])

useEffect(() =>{
  fetch("/details").then(
    res => res.json()
  ).then(
    data => {
      setData(data)
      console.log(data)
    }
  )
}, [])
```

That `console.log(data)` does show my the JSON response in the console.

Then I do  this for the display.

```jsx
return (
  <div>
    ...
    <div>
      {(typeof data.members === 'undefined') ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        data.members.map((member, i) => (
          <p key={i}>{member}</p>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

This is supposed to display "Loading..." while the data is being fetched and then display the data. But it keeps displaying "Loading..." even though my data was fetched and it's never displayed.

I tried what emrich said and got this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

```
App
D:/React/Candetect/src/App.jsx:32
  29 | <FileList files={files} removeFile={removeFile} />
  30 | <div>
  31 | {(data.length === 0) ? (
> 32 |   <p>Loading...</p>
     | ^  33 | ) : (
  34 |   data.members.map((member, i) => (
  35 |     <p key={i}>{member}</p>

D:/React/Candetect/src/App.jsx:15
  12 |   res => res.json()
  13 | ).then(
  14 |   data => {
> 15 |     setData(data)
     | ^  16 |     console.log(data)
  17 |   }
  18 | )
```

This is the object from the backend

```
{
    "Information": [
        {
            "college_name": null,
            "company_names": [
                "Marathwada Mitra Mandal’s College of Engineering"
            ],
            "degree": [
                "B.E. IN COMPUTER ENGINEERING"
            ],
            "designation": [
                "Machine Learning",
                "TECHNICAL CONTENT WRITER",
                "Schlumberger\nDATA ENGINEER"
            ],
            "email": "omkarpathak27@gmail.com",
            "experience": [
                "Schlumberger",
                "DATA ENGINEER",
                "July 2018 - Present",
                "• Responsible for implementing and managing an end-to-end CI/CD Pipeline with custom validations for Informatica migrations which",
                "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
                "brought migration time to 1.5 hours from 9 hours without any manual intervention",
                "• Enhancing, auditing and maintaining custom data ingestion framework that ingest around 1TB of data each day to over 70 business",
                "units",
                "• Working with L3 developer team to ensure the discussed Scrum PBI’s are delivered on time for data ingestions",
                "• Planning and Executing QA and Production Release Cycle activities",
                "Truso",
                "FULL STACK DEVELOPER INTERN",
                "• Created RESTful apis",
                "• Tried my hands on Angular 5/6",
                "• Was responsible for Django backend development",
                "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
                "June 2018 - July 2018",
                "Propeluss",
                "DATA ENGINEERING INTERN",
                "• Wrote various automation scripts to scrape data from various websites.",
                "• Applied Natural Language Processing to articles scraped from the internet to extract different entities in these articles using entity",
                "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
                "October 2017 - January 2018",
                "extraction algorithms and applying Machine Learning to classify these articles.",
                "• Also applied KNN with LSA for extracting relevant tags for various startups based on their works.",
                "GeeksForGeeks",
                "TECHNICAL CONTENT WRITER",
                "• Published 4 articles for the topics such as Data Structures and Algorithms and Python",
                "Pune, Maharashtra, India",
                "July 2017 - September 2017",
                "Softtestlab Technologies",
                "WEB DEVELOPER INTERN",
                "• Was responsible for creating an internal project for the company using PHP and Laravel for testing purposes",
                "• Worked on a live project for creating closure reports using PHP and Excel"
            ],
            "mobile_number": "8087996634",
            "name": "Omkar Pathak",
            "no_of_pages": 3,
            "skills": [
                "Python",
                "Cloud",
                "Github",
                "Django",
                "Writing",
                "Unix",
                "Algorithms",
                "C",
                "Windows",
                "Training",
                "C++",
                "Flask",
                "Scrum",
                "Testing",
                "Reports",
                "Programming",
                "Operating systems",
                "Automation",
                "Engineering",
                "Html",
                "Css",
                "Analytics",
                "Opencv",
                "Content",
                "Excel",
                "Mysql",
                "Migration",
                "Api",
                "Parser",
                "Machine learning",
                "System",
                "Php",
                "Apis",
                "Auditing",
                "Technical",
                "Photography",
                "Shell",
                "Linux",
                "Security",
                "Website",
                "Javascript"
            ],
            "total_experience": 4.5
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you set the initial value of the `data` state to an array, but use it as an object. `( data.members )`

If the data come from API is an object not an array, You need to set it as an object.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({})
```

Then you can check if the object has been set or not, you can check by the length of the object keys

```
  return (
<div>
...
  <div>
  {Object.values(data).length ? (
    <p>Loading...</p>
  ) : (
    data.members.map((member, i) => (
      <p key={i}>{member}</p>
    ))
  )}
</div>
</div>
```

);

Answer (score 0):

I would edit the code like:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
```

```
    useEffect(() =>{
      fetch("/details").then(
        res => res.json()
      ).then(
        data => {
          setData(data.Information)
          console.log(data.Information)
        }
      )
    }, [])
```

```
(
    <div>
    ...
      <div>
      {(data.length === 0) ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : (
        data.map((member, i) => (
          <p key={i}>{member.college_name}</p>
        ))
      )}
    </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Its likely, that members is still undefined after setting the state.

Comment: I get this error instead, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). I'll update the question and display the error I get from your edit.

Comment: Perfect, then just remove the object you initially put into the array. Then, your solution should be working.

Comment: Sorry I'm not so sure I understand what you mean

Comment: const [data, setData] = useState([])

Comment: Now, the page loads up, I get Loading, then as the data is fetched it gives me the same error

Comment: Please show me what the output of the console.log(data) in your console looks like.

Comment: Updated the answer, it's a bit lengthy

Comment: Ok, instead of setData(data) you should use setData(data.Information)

Comment: Now, I'm getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Comment: With a big i instead of i so I

Comment: Ok no more erros thank goodness. But the data isn't getting displayed

Comment: Now you can access the different fields like <p key={i}>{member.college_name}</p>

Comment: If you want, you can accept and like my answer :D

Comment: I'll accept your answer because it did remove these errors but I still can't access the different fields as you say. I tried <p key={i}>{member.email}</p> which isn't null or empty and nothing gets displayed

Comment: actually errors are still there. I just did data.members?.map((member, i) added ? and it removed the error. once i remove it I still get the same error. I'm not quite sure what's going on but I think it's considering the data to be undefined for some reason

Comment: Could we move this to chat?

Comment: just remove the members like in my answer. You only need data.map(...)